# Oracle DATE Comparison and TimeZones

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am a newbie to Oracle and have been banging my head trying to understand how the Oracle DATE type works.

I have a Java Date object with timezone information. From what I understand, the Java Date object is normalized to number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. This Date object is then saved to the database via JDBC API. The prepared statement looks something like this:

ps.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp.Timestamp(date.getTime()));

This is done to capture the date and time information.

The database column corresponding to this index is of type oracle DATE. When I store this java.sql.Timestamp.Timestamp object value in to Oracle DATE field, does it store the normalized date (number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970) ? Thus, no matter which timezone the database is in, the data that gets stored in to the oracle DATE column will be the same normalized data, correct ?

If I were to compare this DATE column in a where clause with SYSDATE will the SYSDATE also be normalized when a comparison is done. I am not sure how the comparison is done in oracle since the oracle server can be in a different timezone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A DATE type will store the time portion of the date down to a second granularity, if you need further detail then you should consider a TIMESTAMP type (http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2234501/A-Comparison-of-Oracles-DATE-and-TIMESTAMP-Datatypes.htm). For a full breakdown of timezone support in DATE types: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm

Answer (score 0):

Both `DATE` values will be normalized.

When I made simple Oracle query with Jython:

```
rs = c.executeQuery("select sysdate from dual")
while (rs.next()):
    print('%s' % (SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z").format(rs.getTimestamp(1))))
```

I got:

```
2011-11-04 09:58:00 +0100
```

And while I live in Poland we have '+0100' time zone.